# Using jQuery to create nested [ CLOSED ]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nested

I want to create a list item with a lot of divs, and classes.
I can not find a suitable way to do so, I am looking for a short work around this.

This is the html code I want to add:

```
<li>
    <div class="note">
        <div class="top_note">
            <ul class="right_ui">
                <li class="favno"></li>
                <li class="type"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="left_ui">
                <li class="edit"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

This is only one of the divs that I want to add, there is another div after that with a  "ul". 

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Try this:


$('<your li selector>').html(`<div class="note">
    <div class="top_note">
         <ul class="right_ui">
             <li class="favno"></li>
             <li class="type"></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="left_ui">
              <li class="edit"></li>
         </ul>
</div>`);

Surround the html content with backticks. (can't write them here because they are getting interpreted as start and end codeblock)

Comment: Look for jQuery `.append()`

Comment: [The `jQuery()` doco has examples](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) of creating nested elements using a string of html. Any number of jQuery tutorials cover this too.

Comment: @André Senra: normal single quotes are ok.

Comment: If the code is single lined yes, but i wrote it with line breaks, that's why i was using backticks ` :)

Comment: @AndréSenra Thanks a lot, I was using single quotes and that why the error was occurring. :)  Feel so dumb that I didn't knew about bacticks (╥﹏╥). I feel dumping html as string is the simplist way for me to go :P

Comment: @MuneebR - be warned, `backticks` for multiline strings are not supported by IE10/11 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple jquery way of doing it:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var parentDiv = $('#myDiv');
    var note = $('<div />', { 'class': 'note' });
    var top_note = $('<div />', { 'class': 'top_note' });
    var right_ui = $('<ul />', { 'class': 'right_ui' });
    var left_ui = $('<ul />', { 'class': 'left_ui' });

    right_ui.append($('<li />', { 'class': 'favno' }));
    right_ui.append($('<li />', { 'class': 'type' }));
    left_ui.append($('<li />', { 'class': 'edit' }));

    top_note.append(right_ui);
    top_note.append(left_ui);

    note.append(top_note);
    parentDiv.append($('<li />').append(note));
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="myDiv">

    </div>
```